# SubClass variables do not get initialized again

Tags: java

I have my main class from which i call my sub class.

My sub class contains some public static  variables like

```
    public class SubClass2 extends Main {


     public static  long a = 0;
     public static  long b = 0;
     public static  long c= 0;

    public void Analyze(int number)
    {
      b=2;

    //some code
     }
    }
```

Where as in main i call the object of the SubClass2.I want everytime when i make the new object of the subclass2 in main then it initializes 
all the variables =0 but when i take the print statement of the variable b.It prints out like 4.It adds up the previous value with the new value.

[image]

Comment: static  method or a variable is not attached to a particular object, but rather to the class as a whole. They are allocated when the class is loaded. Remember, each time you call the instance the new value of the variable is provided to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your fields should not be declared as `static` in that case. This is why they're not being initialised each time. A `static` field is initialised once only, then shared by every instance of the class, and depending on accessibility, also outside of the class.

The logic that led to the value `4` must be in the code you've replaced with `//some code`, but this ins't really relevant here.

If for whatever reason these really should be `static` fields that are initialised each time an instance is instantiated, then you would have to initialise them manually in the class's constructor. But I'd seriously question the design that leads to this situation...

Comment: Okay so i should write all these variables in a constructor if i want to access them in different classes and want to initialize them again  whenever i have to  restart my project

Comment: "should" is overstating it. You imply when you say "restart my project" that there is only one instance of this class? Should it not effectively be a static class in that case, i.e. should `Analyze` not also be static? If there are multiple instances, they you can still give access to these fields on the instance variable rather than in a static context (or even better by exposing `getA`, `getB` methods etc.).

Comment: When i restart my project then there will be only one instance of this Subclass. Are u saying that i should make the methods in subclass also static?

Comment: If there's only one instance, then why not? But also, if there's only one instance, why are you worried about the variables resetting each time you instantiate? Still not convinced we have the full picture to help you here...

Comment: i have edited my main post.Hope it will help you to understand my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are using static variables. These have no connection to any objects you create. They are just global, unique variables. You must erase `static`. By the way, it is redundant to initialize a field to 0. It is already initialized to zero.

Comment: "Global"? "Unique"? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Just like a global var in C -- visible from everywhere, unique as in singleton. A single memory location. You said they are "shared by every instance of class", which is misleading at best. They are shared by the whole JVM (or, more precisely, the ClassLoader that loaded the class).

Comment: I am accessing these variables in a ,b and c in some more classes as well.That's why i made them static.Is there any other way that i can access the in other classes as well.

Comment: But you are accessing the variables that belong to a particular object -- that's what you said you want, no? Then you must use a reference to that object in all the places you want to access the variables from.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the word static there will only ever be one instance of the variable that is shared between everything created that uses it. Remove static and there will be a new, but more importantly, individual variable for each time its initialised in a method.

Perhaps better wording is that instance methods can and will access shared/static variables!

Answer (score 1):

Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. Static variables are initialized once, when the class is loaded. If you want variables initialized per-instance, use per-instance (non-static) variables.